# Error in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-support-library

I have worked on android development with `eclipse`, I tried the new Android studio and created the first project and I am getting the following error.

```
Error: Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':Helloworld'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':Helloworld:_DebugCompile'.
      > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+.
        Required by:
            HelloworldProject:Helloworld:unspecified
```

can anyone please help me to solve with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your Android SDK Manager, and under Extras, install the Android Support Repository.